# How to lock a RHEL 5.3 workstation

Tags: linux, workstation, rhel-5, logout

I get option to SUSPEND/HIBERNATE or reboot/shutdown. Isn't there something similar to locking as in windows.

I don't want to log out each time I want a break(think bathroom, drink).

I would expect that after I have LOCKED the workstation, I would have to log back in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>. This is configurable in Keyboard Shortcuts.

Comment: but this does only switch off/dim the monitor. I want to LOCK the screen so that nobody can access my programs from my monitor.

Comment: Then tell your screensaver settings to lock it.

Comment: I tried that but it says that the "SCREEN WILL NOT BE LOCKED FOR THE ROOT USER". unfortunately, I am logged in as root.

Comment: Well that would be your fault.

Comment: agreed. that's my fault.